# Custom template files for multiple blocks provided by a custom module?

Tags: theming, blocks

The custom module is called, "epic_module". It defines several blocks, say "awesome_block" and "epic_block".

```
function epic_module_block_info() {
  $blocks['awesome_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Awesome block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  $blocks['epic_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Epic Block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function epic_module_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'awesome_block':
      // TO-DO: Set $block['content'], etc...
      break;
    case 'epic_block':
      // TO-DO: Set $block['content'], etc...
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

I have also created a templates directory under my module's directory.

I'm confused by the naming conventions. I want to link the template files for the specified blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a different template file for your blocks, by default Drupal uses the following template files.

- block--epic-module.tpl.php for all the blocks implemented by the module you are showing
- block--epic-module--awesome-block.tpl.php and block--epic-module--epic-block.tpl.php for the blocks implemented by that code

Keep in mind that each underscore in the module name or in the block name (i.e. what the documentation calls *delta*) is replaced with a hyphen.

#### Reference

- [`template_preprocess_block()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7.x)